# Can AggregateRating in Schema Be Extended to include a Source or URL Property?

Tags: schema, json-ld

I don't really know if there is a way around it, kindly chip in your suggestions.

I think `aggregateRating` of an entity is limiting in schema markup. If there is a possibility of extension I believe an attribute such as `source` or `url` would be great because we can tell from which source the rating is coming from.

Challenge scenario:
I am marking up a schema for a book, this book has ratings on both goodreads.com and amazon.com. Both ratings are different, however, there is no way to account for the different aggregate ratings since it is not available at the moment. I don't think it is cool to just take an average.

Right now:

```
  "keys": "values",

  "aggregateRating": {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "reviewCount": "25",
      "ratingValue": "5"
  },
```

Suggestion:

```
  "keys": "values",

  "aggregateRating": [
    {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "reviewCount": "25",
      "ratingValue": "5",
      "source": "https://amzn.com/product/url/reviews"
    },
    {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "reviewCount": "5",
      "ratingValue": "4",
      "source": "https://gdreads.com/product/url/reviews"
    }
  ],
```

[image: Multi aggregate rating throws an error.]

Comment: I've seen a few people use url to indicate where the third party reviews came from. Your suggested solution for the split is interesting. It would be nice to know if it works with Google.

Comment: What makes you think that you *couldn’t* use the `url` property?

Comment: @uno here is why, Only one aggregate rating should be marked up. ![Multi Aggregate rating] (https://res.cloudinary.com/tonyfrenzy/image/upload/v1558805721/Multi_Aggregate_rating.png

Comment: @AyeniTonyOpe: But this error is related to providing multiple `AggregateRating` items, not related to providing the `url` of these `AggregateRating` items, no?

Comment: @unor, the main reason for this question was about how to add multiple Aggregate Ratings as illustrated in my "Suggestion" part of the question. 

Just like you can add multiple entries for other attributes eg 
```"image": "https://ex.com/image.jpg"``` 
or 
```"image": { "https://ex.com/image.jpg",  "https://ex.com/image-2.jpg"}```

But for aggregateRating you cannot add more than one and you may have different sources of aggregate rating as in this scenario 1). Amazon Books and 2). Goodreads